# Cryptographically hash multiple keys

Tags: c++, cryptography

How to hash using `SHA1`(or similar cryptogrphical functions) a class(or struct) which **has multiple keys**, e.g.,

```
struct Foo{
   string name;
   int age;
   int score;
}
```

A naive approach is `hash(has(name) + hash(age) + hash(score))`, but hash collision is possible.

Comment: And what's the question now?

Comment: Collision is always a possibility - you may be able to reduce the likelihood of that by using a more sophisticated combination function than addition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either hash the whole structure directly if it contains only POD (i.e. nothing allocated within and its `sizeof` is a constant): either you can use an `union` to get a proper byte array, or you use a cast to obtain a `char*` to provide to hash function.

If you have dynamic data inside your struct/class, you need to serialize all data and send them to the hash function - obviously, its size will vary during execution, because of dynamic data. But you must call `hash` only **ONCE** per data structure, and in **NO WAY** adding hashes together - that's a nonsense.
You can also use a framework feature that will serialize your struct/class to a text stream (often XML or JSON format), and hash this serialization instead of the binary structure.

How to do all this is obviously platform-dependent - which cryptography API do you use, if you prefer.

By applying these principles, the collision (totally unavoidable, mathematically proven) won't be more than for any other kind of hashed data.

Comment: using JSON is a pretty nice method. Thanks.

Comment: @Blade You're welcome. If it suits yourself, you can tag it as accepted. However, even if serializing to JSON/XML is a working and quite simple solution if you have these functions already available, don't forget that do it on binary data will be way more efficient and fast, because it involves the same class/struct parsing than serialization, but without the need to transform it to text before hashing.

Comment: can't agree more. JSON is easier to implement, but performance is definitely slower than processing raw bytes.